# Python application multi-threading for dev environment only

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

I am working on a Python/bottle app that has two components:

- A REST endpoint that receives messages and drops them on a queue (in Redis)
- A 'worker', which is an infinite loop that polls for messages and processes them

In production, the two will be run in separate processes, but I'd like to run them both in the same process when running locally for development purposes.

Threading seems like the obvious answer, but threading is unnecessary when running the components in separate processes.

Is there an elegant way to optionally employ a threaded approach only when running both components in the same process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should not be a problem since it sounds like they are completely isolated. I would just add a new script that imports threading and then either wraps the other starter scripts in functions or calls the functions they use with the new threads.

Here is a simple example:

```
import threading

def script1():
    import script1
def script2():
    import script2

t1 = threading.Thread(target=script1)
t2 = threading.Thread(target=script2)
t1.start()
t2.start()
t1.join()
t2.join()
```

That would start anything in the scripts main section of the scripts, more ideally if the script had an actual main function you could run that in the threads.

A few things to note:

- If they are dealing with any singletons or globals they could end up tromping on each other.
- Also since python has a GIL they might not run as fast and/or have different timings then the scripts in production.
- A work around to both problems could be to use the multiprocessing module, they would not be in the same process, but they could be ran from the same script at the same time.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up doing things a bit differently, using a command line arg to determine whether to run all processes or just one. That feels "closer to production" to me (yes I see the irony), but the separate wrapper script works just fine as well.